# How to modify default color on MudRating icon

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

i have developed a simple one page app with Blazor ( a simple customer satisfaction survey ).
I'm using MudBlazor, MudRating to be more specific.

```
<MudRating @bind-SelectedValue="product_quality" MaxValue="4" FullIcon="@Icons.Material.Rounded.RadioButtonChecked" EmptyIcon="@Icons.Material.Rounded.RadioButtonUnchecked"></MudRating>
```

There is a way to modify the default icon color used on ther MudRating component?
I have tried using

```
Color="Color.Info"
```

But it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried other colors aswell? Aren't these workin aswell? I got it working in a snippet: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEcdFPurwTOhGNnB
Is your Mudblazor up-to-date?

Comment: You could try edit it's CSS style using <style>. You would need to investigate in browser tools where the colour is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added "MudThemeProvider":

```
<MudThemeProvider Theme="defualt"></MudThemeProvider>
```

and on the @code

```
MudTheme defualt = new MudTheme()
{
    Palette = new Palette()
    {
        Info = "#1C7CCE"
    }
};
```

[image]

Thank you.

EDIT: I have edited the "Info" color to be sure that it will match with the color of another button in the app.